# CXF JAX-RS Client - Avoiding the need to override toString of POJOs

Tags: java, cxf, jax-rs

I'm calling the following method from a JAX-RS client.

```java
@POST
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
public Book createBook(Book b);
```

It typically calls `b.toString()` to marshall it. Assuming that I do not have control on class `Book` (it has it's own `toString()`), is there a way I can tell the client to use a particular library/factory/something else to marshal the object into JSON instead of calling `toString()`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using jackson?  If not,  I would look at it: [CXF Jackson](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-data-bindings.html#JAX-RSDataBindings-Jackson)

Since createBook is declared to return string, if you try to return it, it will use toString.

I'm wondering why you just don't return Book if that's what's coming out.  I personally normally return Response from my methods and then build the response.  That may be overkill in your case.

Comment: I'm talking about marshaling parameter, and not return type. However, edited return type to be Book -- looks more meaningful. Thanks.